# IDrawable interface vs. Draw event

Tags: c#, oop, events, interface

I'm in the process of programming a piece of simulator software which is supposed to be able to have a graphical interface in which specific portions of the simulation are displayed. The output isn't very complex, so I'm using GDI.

Regarding implementation, I've come up with two possibilities, and was wondering if any one of them is generally superior than the other.

**Creating an IDrawable interface**

```
interface IDrawable
{
    void Draw(Graphics e);
}

class Simulation : Control
{

    public readonly Collection<IDrawable> Drawables { get; private set; }

    public Simulation() {
        Drawables = new Collection<IDrawable>();
    }

    protected override OnPaint( /* ... */ ) {
        foreach (IDrawable drawable in Drawables) {
            drawable.Draw(e.Graphics);
        }
    }

}
```

**Using events**

```
class SomeObject
{

    private readonly Simulation _parent;

    public SomeObject(Simulation parent) {
         _parent = parent;
         _parent.Paint += _parent_Paint;
    }

    private void _parent_Paint( /* ... */ ) {
         // 
    }

}
```

Personally, I'm leaning towards the first option, as I've seen it successfully used elsewhere (e.g. XNA if I'm not mistaken), but are there any practical advantages to the second option?

To me, it also seems that the second option creates a disconnection between SomeObject and the instance of Simulation it belongs to. Basically, the latter only knows about its method pointer (_parent_Paint), not about the instance itself, which I'm not sure is too good of an idea.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: I'd stick with #1 but it's opinion based question. It seems to me more readable and logical than your second option

Comment: Second option assumes what collection of objects is someone else job (not the `parent`). It's also risky to subscribe to some event of some object, if `parent` lives long, then you will need to unsubscribe somewhere. While first option is very clean and common.

Comment: Alright thanks, you've just strengthened my decision. I'll be using the first method; it seems more readable and clean to me as well.